# Ruta al Servidor Error

Tags: c#, iis, windows-server-2012, certificado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando voy a buscar una ruta al servidor me sale el siguiente error en el LOG,

**Debe establecerse una confianza con el equipo para delegación y la cuenta de usuario actual deberá configurarse para permitir la delegación.**

Cabe mencionar que estoy ocupando window server 2012 R2, y active la carga de perfil de usuario, ya que lo que necesito es rescatar un archivo pfx para conectarme al SII, localmente funciona excelente el problema es que necesito probarlo localmente en el servidor y ahi es donde esta el problema.

Comment: Generalmente los certificados se instalan en el servidor y luego los buscas por huella digital, busca un poco sobre eso, la consola donde agregas eso se abre ejecutando "mmc" en Ejecutar (WIN + R)

Answer (score 0):

Problema con sacar el certificado desde el iis:

> 1. Dar permiso a IIS AppPool\mydomain.com a la carpeta que se  va a compartir en el mismo servidor.

Ejm. Te vas a tu carpeta c:\LOG click derecho propiedades, pestaña seguridad, luego editar, luego agregar, en la ubicación seleccionas el nombre del servidor (no todo el directorio)y ahí colocas IIS AppPool\mydomain.com, cambiando mydomain.com por el nombre de pool de tu aplicación si es el default: IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool

> 2. Cambiar la configuración del AppPool en la cual le tenemos que colocar “True” a load user profile.

Ej. te vas al iis manager, luego application pool, abres la configuración avanzada del pool con la que estas trabajando, buscas load user profile y le colocas True

> 3. En caso de error se le da permisos a IIS_IUSR en la carpeta que deseas sacar el certificado.

Ej. Lo Mismo que el punto uno solo que buscas IIS_IUSR

Comment: Ya lo hice, no me funciona